# To prove a sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

If a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of real numbers satisfies $$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\Arrowvert x_n-x_{n+1}\Arrowvert=0$$,can we prove that it is a convergent sequence?

I have tried to prove it is a Cauchy sequence but it seems hard to deal with the part of $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: No, we cannot, for a counterexample, try $$x_n=\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k\log k}$$

Comment: @Did Ok,I see it. Thank you very much!